# How do I read plain text from a binary file?

Tags: c, regex

I have following text include control character,please see the image ,these control character does not display when I copy from Notepad++ to paste in this question

[image]

Have any way to grab just "HIEUDT" string in this text ? I have no idea about substring function with control character

In another language ,maybe I will using a regex start with `\a` character and `0x04` ,but in C I have no experience about it

Comment: This is binary format. It's probably well-defined and has particular structure. If so, it should be read accordingly - parsed. Have you tried that? Regex might work, but it's not exactly right approach.

Comment: `BEL` should be` 0x07` and `DC4` should be `0x14`. Use [strok](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) to find delimiters. Or better and safer in your case, go through your array looking for BEL, and then collect chars until DC4

Comment: I get this text  from socket message ,does any suggest to me about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   int i=0, j=0;
   while ((data[i] != 0x07) && (i<dataLen))
      i++;

   char *subString = malloc((dataLen-i)+1);

   if (subString != NULL)
   {
      while ((data[i] != 0x14) && (i<dataLen))
         subString[j++] = data[i++];

      if (i<dataLen)
      {
         subString[j] = '\0';
         printf("%s", subString);
      }
      else
      {
         printf("Delimiters not found");
      }

      free (subString);
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use standard string functions for this:

```
char *start = memchr(data, '\x07', datalen);
start++;
char *end = memchr(start, '\x14', datalen-(start-data));
int len = end - start;
char str[len+1];
memcpy(str, data, len);
str[len] = '\0';
```

You must of course check if `memchr` does not return `NULL` each time.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int extractStr(char *out,const char *in, char Delim1, char Delim2){
    int n=0;
    while(*in){
        if(*in==Delim1){                // first delimiter found?
            in++;
            while(in[n] ){

                if(in[n]==Delim2){      // second delimiter found?
                    if(out) out[n]=0;      // null terminate out if provided
                    return n;
                }else{
                    if(out) 
                        out[n]= in[n];  // copy back to out if provided
                }
                n++;
            }
            in+=n;

        }
        in++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){

    char *buff;
    int n;
    char str[]="jksdqsqd sqjhd\bresult\x04qsjhgsdsqs";

    n=extractStr(NULL,str,'\b',0x04);

    if(n){
        buff=malloc(n);
        n=extractStr(buff,str,'\b',0x04);
        printf("'%s'\n",buff);
        free(buff);
    }else
        printf("string not found\n");
    return 0;
}
```